# can user developed android app can behave like built in app?

Tags: android

Is that possible to make user developed android app to behave like built in app so that even after hard reset application can be auto installed with out downloading from play store. Not sure this is possible or Google will allow to it... Any help much appreciated

Comment: are you asking if a user built app can be stored as an OS app? And by hard reset, do you mean reformatting? It sounds like the answer is no, but maybe I'm not following what you're asking for.

Comment: Yes you are right Kai, yes even if i format it i would like to have this app again?

Comment: Yes. All you have to do is negotiate a contract with device manufacturers to include your app in their ROM image.